# Prism 6 interactivity - how do I use these functions in a Win10 UAP App?

Tags: mvvm, unity-container, prism, uwp

I see that the Interactivity namespace was moved into the Prism.Wpf package since V6 - how do I access this functionality in a Win10 UAP app?

Comment: What's the downvote for?  I've tried installing the Prism.Wpf package using the Nuget console and it tells me that the package is not compatible with UAP.  So how am I supposed to use the interactivity namespace in a UAP app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prism.Wpf is for WPF only and thus not compatible with Windows 10 UWP (binary wise).

For Windows 8.1 RT / Windows 10 UWP you currently can add a reference to the Behaviors SDK. Note that it targets Windows 8.1, but it works under Windows 10 as well.

[image]

An alternative to adding the reference is opening Blend, and dragging a behavior from the Assets tab onto your page. This will add a reference as well.

Even better news is that Microsoft is working on a NuGet library for Windows 10 UWP behaviors, which should be available in approx. 1 month and will be made open source. So anyone reading this in the future, should look for the package.

Comment: Thank-you Bart.  I was rather hoping that the richer functionality available to WPF would also be available in UWP.

Comment: It will be eventually, but first we need the final behaviors sdk for uwp.